# Executing PowerShell script remotely yields different results

Tags: c#, powershell

I've written a C# code that's supposed to retrieve all installed Appx packages on a Win8 machine. When running it locally I get the expected results. However, while running it remotely from a different host I get unusual results - meaning I don't get all the packages installed. This also changes from execution to execution - including running it twice consecutively from the same host and on the same machine without any changes.

This is the basic structure of the code:

```
PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

powerShell.AddCommand("Get-AppxPackage");

Collection<PSObject> psObjects = powerShell.Invoke();
```

Has anyone experienced this before? What could be causing this? (I'm running the script as an Admin on the target machine)

Thanks in advance